# Where to draw the line between preprint and author-submitted paper?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, terminology, ieee, preprint

I read on https://conferences.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/get-published/post-your-paper/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191107025921/https://conferences.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/get-published/post-your-paper/)):

> - **Preprint**: a form of e-print where an author posts a draft paper on the author’s or another website. The preprint is the paper in the form prior to submission to IEEE.
> - **Author-submitted paper**: the version of the paper originally submitted by the author to an IEEE publication.

Where to draw the line between preprint and author-submitted paper?

For example, if I fix a typo in my paper draft right before submitting it, was the  paper draft before the typo fix a preprint and the paper draft after the typo fix the author-submitted paper?

Comment: While this is technically a legal matter, I don't see how anyone could conceivably benefit from you intentionally using a version of the manuscript that *includes* a known typo.  I don't think IEEE will sue you.  I would absolutely use the corrected version.

Comment: Where to draw the line between madness and sanity? Actually never mind, I’m pretty sure I know which side of that line the policy you‘re quoting falls on...